# How minimize the output window in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to minimize & maximize the output window in Oracle SQL Developer (the equivalent to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> in SSMS)

Is there any option available in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Developer 17.4 (I believe in other recent versions too), when you run a query, the result is displayed in the "Query Result" window.

Right above the green arrow (which is displayed as the tab icon), in the upper left corner of the "Query Result" window, you'll notice two small black triangles, pointing up (*maximize*) and down (*minimize*). These two are what you're looking for.